# What does a 404 mean in the context of a Google Calendar API?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I am trying to programatically access a calendar I own using the [Google Calendar API `list`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list):

```
r = requests.get(
        url="https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/<the ID of my calendar which looks like mydomain_randomstuff@group.calendar.google.com>/events",
        params={
            'key': <the key from the API console>,
            'singleEvents': True,
            'orderBy': 'startTime'
        }
```

This call fails with a `404`:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "Not Found"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Not Found"
 }
}
```

What does that error actually mean, **in the context of this API**?

Note:

- the calendar does exist and it has events
- the API limits are not even close to be reached

Comment:  I guessed that this code is JavaScript if not please fix the tag with the correct programming language you are using.

Comment: @DaImTo: I removed the JS tag as the question is not related to any specific language but to the API. I used  Python in the example but it does not matter

Comment: That doesnt look like code from the google api python client library but my python knowledge is limited.

Comment: @DaImTo: no, this is a `requests` call, which is the implementation of HTTP calls in Python (similar to `fetch` in JS since you mentioned it - just synchronous)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "Not Found"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Not Found"
 }
}
```

Can mean one of two things.  Either the calendar Id you have typed is in correct or the user who you are authenticated with does not have access to that calendar.  Make sure you are logging in with the correct user with access to that calendar.  Optionally you can do a [calendar.list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list) which will return a list of the calendars that the user currently has access to.  That way you wont have to worry about possibly miss typing the calendar id.

## authorization

The method you are using [events.list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) requires authorization (permission from the user) in order to access their calendar. Which can be seen in the documentation page

[image]

You need to authncate your user using Oauth2 and one of the scopes above.  You will then have an access token you can use to access this calendar.

## apikey

Api keys are used for accessing public data.  Unless your calendar is set to public you will not be able to use it to see events.  Also remember that api keys do not have access to update public calendars you still need to be authenticated to make changes to them.

## Service account

If this is a server to server application you should use a service account not an API key. All you need to do is add the service account as a user on the google calendar like you would any other user.  It will then have access to your calendar.

Comment: This is a server to server call, so I use the API key. 404 is "not found" (whatever that means in reality), a lack of authorization would be 401 or 403, right? My core problem is that the 404 is not documented anywhere (or at least I did not find it). Also, the calendar ID is correct.

Comment: Yes its probably lack of authorization make sure the calendar is set to public if you want to use an api key to select data.   I have updated my answer.

Comment: You are right, thanks for the update. I did not realize that the key is for quota management, not for any kind of authentication.